# Ubuntu with plesk 17 spamassasin not working

Tags: ubuntu, spam-prevention, plesk, spamassassin

at the moment I got very much spam mails. All of them are polish and have a spamscore of more then 5.5.

So I thought yeah easys just adjust spamassasin in my plesk panel to 5 and the spam  is filtered.

But no.... all the mails come through. I think spamassasin is not working. But its enabled and the system setting is set to 4 and the setting for the mailadress as well.

what can I do to prevent the spam ...

thanks

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if SpamAssasin is not enabled for mailbox/domain/server. So service itself can be running, but it does not remove of flag the spam.

First make sure that SpamAssasin is running:
Open **Plesk > Tools & Settings > Services Management**

Next check that it is enabled for mailbox:
**Subscriptions > example.com > Mail > jdoe@example.com > Switch on spam filtering for this email address**

Or globally in **Plesk > Tools & Settings > Mail Server settings**

Also you can test it by sending a message containing the following string of characters in message body (in upper case and with no spaces or line breaks):

*XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X*

Check the `/var/log/maillog` for lines like:

```
Dec 3 20:52:48 pleskserver spamd[1107]: spamd: identified spam (1000.0/7.0) for test@domain.tld:110 in 6.1 seconds, 3926 bytes.
```

These lines show that spam was detected.

Reference [article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213926245-I-am-getting-too-much-spam-How-can-I-check-that-SpamAssasin-is-working-fine-).